# How to ensure winrm service is started at boot?

Tags: winrm

Reading the documentation for winrm, I thought that doing winrm quickconfig as admin (windows 7) was needed only once, and that winrm would then starts automatically at boot.

But that does not seem to work for me: how can I check/ensure it is setup to start automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

[Are you sure it's not starting up automatically?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> By default, no WinRM listener is configured. Even if the WinRM service is running, WS-Management protocol messages that request data cannot be received or sent.

[...]

> Use the Winrm command to locate listeners and the addresses by typing the following command at a command prompt: **winrm e winrm/config/listener**. To check the state of configuration settings, type **winrm get winrm/config**.

Having said that, if the problem really is the service not starting up at boot time, you can issue `sc config "WinRM" start= auto` from the command line to change the service to automatic startup, and `net start WinRM` to start it.  If it's already started, it will tell you as much, so that's a way quick check as well.

And there's always service management/`services.msc` for a GUI option.

[image: WinRM]